# Device android buttons how to change button input from * to .?

Tags: android, button, xamarin, onkeydown

I try catch the button "*" click using onkeydown method, but I have no idea how to change " * " to " . " Or there is maybe some other method to do that?

I have a barcode scanner for android. DEVICE have buttons- keys, one of them have "*" and "." as a secound character, but i dont know how to force that button to put dot not a star. I try to use onkeydown method to catch that star, and change charakter to dot programycly. but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Explain more What you want?

Comment: can you add a image ?

Comment: To change the text of a button, you only have to do myButton.setText("your text");

Comment: I think what he wants is, user clicks '*' button, and he wants to grammatically change user input to '.'.

Comment: I am toking about device buttons not buttons forms in application.- Fustigador

Comment: TieDad- exacly. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't ever do this, but try this, see if it works:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STAR:
       keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

If this doesn't work, also try `onKeyDown`.